# Choosing common absolute path for Windows and Linux in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, filesystems

Hello i have the following problem.I want to run a `.NET Core Application` with docker.The app uses a `config.json` file to set up.
While running in `Windows` i just set up an absolute path for the config file like

`C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\App\config.json` and it works all fine.

When running with `docker` i do not know where to copy the `json`,what absolute path i can set for the `config` file that would work for both operating systems

**P,S** In this situation am i forced to use relative paths (app-folder) ? ( `Environment.GetCurrentDirectory`,`Directory.GetParent`..etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/building-net-docker-images) on how to use .net core on Docker & refer this [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples/aspnetapp) project for sample asp.net core Docker sample. As shown in the sample project the appsettings.json is under the root of the project folder and in your Dockerfile you copy the whole project structure in to the image.